# How to test my C program with Python (PyTest) in Travis?

Tags: python, travis-ci, c99

I have a C program which I would like to test with Travis CI.

I currently have a test suite done with *PyTest*, and I want to use this test suite with Travis.

The issue is that *PyTest* fires some issues because it runs parts of subprocess that needs *Python 3*.

So I want to know how can I change the *Python* version, knowing that my program is in C ?

Here is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: c
python:
  - "3.4"

compiler:
  - gcc

install: "pip install --user -r tests/requirements.txt"

before_script:
  - mkdir build
  - cd build
  - cmake ..

script: 
  - make
  - pytest ../tests/
```

Comment: In the provided `.travis.yml`, the `python` version is already set to `3.4`, which sets the default `python` symlink.

Could you provide the exact error message on travis, a link, and possibly the repo?

Comment: @StephenG I am sorry but I cannot provide the repository. However, the issue was fixed using `python3 -m pytest ../tests` and adding `python3` to required packages.